# Laravel - "Other" place holder not accepting friendly names in validation message

Tags: validation, placeholder, laravel

In Laravel,

I am using custom validation in my project to check whether mininum area having smaller value than maximum area. Just created the validation in Validator library

```
public function validate_less_than($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
            $other_value = $this->attributes[$parameters[0]];
            if(!empty($value) && !empty($other_value))
                return $value <= $other_value;
            else    
                return true;    
}
```

added validation message for "less_than", in language file.

```
'less_than'     =>  "The :attribute must be less than :other value",
```

and added  replace placeholder function in validator library, to replace the :other placeholder

```
protected function replace_less_than($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters)
    {
                return str_replace(':other', $parameters[0], $message);
    }
```

my field names are like "min_area", "max_area", so I don't want this field names in validation message, so i have added friendly names for these fields in language files. but ":other" placeholder not taking the friendly names which is specified in validation language file. is it only possible for ":attribute" placeholder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard coded in validator.php at around line 856 (in current version 3.2.12).

You could run it from your replacer tough.

```php
protected function replace_less_than($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters)
{
    return str_replace(':other', $this->attribute($parameters[0]), $message);
}
```

Note the `$this->attribute()`.